# Is there a way to allocate a Bitmap in JNI and use it in Java to avoid OOM error

Tags: android, image-processing, java-native-interface, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I have a drawing-board App and there's an "export image" function. I hope the exported image size can be as large as users want. The exporting steps are:

1. create a bitmap;
2. applying some transformation matrices;
3. create a canvas on that bitmap and draw something on it.
4. compress the bitmap and save to file

When using Java `Bitmap.createBitmap`, if the created bitmap is so large and the required memory reaches Android VM heap size limit, an `OutOfMemoryError` encountered.

To avoid the OOM error I'm considering to create a bitmap with native-allocated pixel data in JNI, and used the bitmap as a reference in Java. But so far I have no idea about how to achieve this at all even after I searched a lot.

Or if I can't do this, is there another way to draw canvas to a probably *very* large bitmap without OOM errors?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

If the end result is a file, you don't need to use Bitmap at all.  Use a C or C++ image library and do everything natively.  It'll also be MUCH faster (in fact Android decodes bitmap in C already, it's too slow in Java and pointers make it easier).

How big is the bitmap anyway?  Remember that a bmp requires `4*width*height` bytes in memory.  There's a limit to how big of one you can create even in C based memory.

Comment: Yes the result is a file. But the main point is for Android, if I want to draw some `Path` to a bitmap, I must do it through a `Canvas`. The java `Bitmap` object is used as the constructor parameter of `Canvas`, and then draw things to `Canvas`. I cannot directly draw Android `Path` to native bitmap object.

Comment: @bczhc Then you're stuck and should try to make the image smaller so you don't go OOM.  Or you need to reduce memory elsewhere.  Or you need to make sure you aren't wasting memory (when you talk about applying matrices, I'd make sure you aren't making temporary copies).  But you're not going to be able to change what pool of memory a Java class allocates from.